# How to made a single child scroll view with a grid view into it?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I wan't to make a page scrollable but with a header fix, so i started with a column with my header and a white space with sizedbox and i add another column with all of my body with a singlechildscrollview, but the problem is, i have a gridView into this column and i can't made this code work? i tried with sliver or adding expanded to column but nothing worked.

This is my code, this code work but don't have the scroll

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          HeaderHome(),
          SizedBox(height: 23.h),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ...Some container with padding
                SizedBox(height: 9.h),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 29.0.w),
                    child: GridView(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 18.h,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 25.h,
                        mainAxisExtent: 195.h,
                      ),
                      children: [
                        ...card.map((e) => inkWell(
                            () => Navigator.push(context,
                                PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeftWithFade, child: EventShowMain())),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                            child: e))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: where is your SingleChildScrollView widget?

Comment: this is why i said, "this code work but withtout the Scroll", because if i wrap my column after my header to made the screen scrollable it's not working.